# MySQL Substring and Sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting

This is my code

```sql
SELECT b.NO_URUT1 FROM HR_REPORT_CONFIG_TAB b WHERE SUBSTR(b.ITEM_ID, 4, 6) = NIK
```

I want to sort **desc by nik** ?

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query on how to provide a minimum reproducible example for SQL queries.

Comment: did you try: `where b.ITEM_ID like '%NIK%' ORDER BY b.ITEM_ID`

Comment: show some sample data and what results you want for that data

Comment: What is `NIK`? Is that another column in the table? Or did you mean to use a text literal `'NIK'`?

Comment: To sort descending by nik: `ORDER BY nik DESC`, as you can see in any article about [SQL sort descending](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+sort+descending).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.NO_URUT1 
FROM HR_REPORT_CONFIG_TAB b 
WHERE b.ITEM_ID = NIK AND SUBSTRING(b.ITEM_ID, 4, 6) 
ORDER BY b.ITEM_ID DESC
```

Can you try something like this? I am not sure whether it correct because there are no sample data.